# How to do JavaScript autocompletion in Geany?

Tags: autocomplete, geany

Is it possible to make in Geany JavaScript autocompletion?

If it is possible it would be better if it will work without Ctrl+Space like in sublime

Comment: How does it work in Sublime?

Comment: Actually it does not matter, I'll be happy to see any autocomplete in Geany. I edit my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your question is not very clear in terms what you expect from auto completion. Geany is supporting e.g. static tags -- which can be self generated or downloaded from the [wiki](http://wiki.geany.org/tags/start#javascript_tags). To enable them go to Tools->Load tags. Also it supports some session based autocompletion, which is turned on by default.

Please take care, as there is a difference between inline JavaScript and explicit JavaScript-file.